# Struts 2 on Google app engine. problem

Tags: java, google-app-engine, struts2

I use struts2 in google app engine I had an error with my application.

```
result 'null' not found
```

But when I created listener OGNL this error is not displaying.

http://whyjava.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/creating-struts2-application-on-google-app-engine-gae/

to resolve this problem I created an `ServletContextListner` which will set OGNL security manager to null when the context is initialized. when I created this listener  this error is not displaying.

But now I have blank page without any text in my browser. When I call to any page, nothing display. Why? Please, help me.

Comment: Provide more info: struts.xml, action for homepage

Answer (score 0):

Empty pages in Struts2 are often related to validation.
Default stack includes validation interceptor which tries to validate all methods except for input,back,cancel,browse:

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Try to call your action with _input appendix (YourAction_input.action) or add execute method to the list of excluded methods for validation interceptor.